# rendering data to html file using express render method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i want to render data concerning the authentication status to my login form which is at index.html:
i tried to do that

```
response.render(__dirname + "/CERIGame/index.html", { 
    errors: "authentication failed" 
});
```

but it doesn't work; need help

here is my project tree:

[image]

and here my server.js file:

```
 app.get('/login', function(request, response) {

    var username = request.query['username'];
    var password = request.query['password'];

    if (username == "" || password == "") {
        response.render(__dirname + "/CERIGame/index.html", { errors: "authentication failed" });
    }
});
```

i want to display the errors variable content in my index.html

```
<div class="body"></div>
<div class="grad"></div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="header">
        <div><b>Bienvenue sur<span>qUIZZ CERI</span><b></div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<form class="col-xs-8" method="get" action="/login">
    <div class="login">
        <input type="text" placeholder="username"name="username"><br>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password"name="password"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What view engine are you using

Comment: i want to use only html so i did that  app.set('view engine', 'html');
knowing that index.html is not in the views folder you can see the project tree image above.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible by setting view engine as html. You can use ejs view engine, it is fully html even you can add dynamic code in it like above!!

Comment: but how to set view engine when index.html isn't in views folder ?